# When should Typography be used in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI and I'm a little confused. There is the component [`Typography`](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/#typography) but I can't really understand when to use it and what is its purpose.

When should `Typography` be used? What problem does it solve/helps or what benefits will I have if I use it while developing?

An example would be very good for me to understand it better.

Comment: I believe that is just a way of standardize the text through your application.
"The type scale is a combination of 13 styles that are supported by the type system. It contains reusable categories of text, each with an intended application and meaning." Makes sense

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705789/what-are-the-valid-values-for-material-uis-typography-component/56708450#56708450

Comment: Another related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862959/how-do-i-get-typography-theme-defaults-to-apply-to-regular-tags-with-material-ui

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Dupocas said, it is the way of standardize the text.

Using a Typography you can standardize all the categories of text. For example, if you want all your titles to have the same size, font, weight ... you can use it like this:

```
<Typography variant="h1">My Title</Typography>
```

For all your subtitles

```
<Typography variant="subtitle1">My SubTitle</Typography>
```

With that component, you don't have to add a div with a specific className to your text in order to set specific styles. They all are applied on the Typography by default.

Typography have more properties you can pass, like "component" which let you choose the type of html tag to wrap your text. *That wasn't the cases in previouse versions*

```
<Typography variant="body1" component="p">
      My Text
</Typography>
```

Material UI is a great library, making choices for you but letting you make your own choices. All the variants can be customized. You can take a look at Customization section to know how.

Please take look to Typography "API" section, it is useful and helpful.

Hope its helps.

Comment: How does `<Typography variant="h1">My Title</Typography>` and `<Typography variant="h2">My Title 2</Typography>` differ from just using `<h1>My Title</h1>` and `<h2>My Title 2</h2>`?

Comment: @ReturnOfTheMac For one, `Typography` will use the styles of the specific variant which can be customized with a theme that we create. In other words, when we say `variant="h2"`, Material will automatically apply styles for an h2 defined in our theme that we can easily change for any given variant. Another feature is that material will automatically change the color of `Typography` text to contrast with its container. For example if we create an `AppBar` that is green, the `Typography` text within the app bar will be colored so that it is very easily readable against that background.

Comment: Also, specifying the variant as `h1` doesn't necessarily mean the `Typography` will be rendered as an h1. By default it will, but it is possible to set it up so that variant `h1` is rendered as some other html tag.

Comment: Thanks. I guess for accessibility reasons it would probably be a bad idea to override that default behaviour.

Comment: I still dont see how the various typography variants would differ from having various css classes. In both cases, we standardize our texts. How is `<Typography variant="h3">Foo</Typography>` better than `<h3 class="my-h3">Foo</h3>`? If anything, it seems longer. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not get the `Typography` either. Especially when defining `h3` style on CSS level (e.g. `.h3 { color: red }`), it is much easier to type `<h3>Title</h3>` rather than `<Typography variant="h3">Title</Typography>`.